# How to use Selenium inside of a map() function in MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to MapReduce and Hadoop and trying to create a program that loads a bunch of web pages, collects text from the web pages using Selenium and concatenates it to a file "finalInput.txt" I have written the program in Java but am now trying to make it use MapReduce and Hadoop, with the Map() function using Selenium to collect the text and the Reduce() function adding all of the text into one file "totalInput.txt". Would I be able to find a template and pretty much copy and paste my existing java class into the Map() function for MapReduce? If so where could I find a template to get me started?

Below is a diagram of how I would like to structure my project. Please let me know if you have any feedback.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to open up a real browser from within map function or you mean programmatic http call to the endpoint and then parsing the HTML in Java code ?